# Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just want to loop through the results in the database. That's all I am trying to do at this point!  This is the error I get when I try to debug:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

It points to this line:

```
// fill dataset into named table
myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sent");
```

Here is my whole code:

```
    // get connection strings from app.config
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    // connection object
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(conString);

    // create adapter
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from `Sent`", myConn);

    // create command builder
    SqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(myAdapter);

    // create dataset
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    // fill dataset into named table
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sent");

    // query using linq
    IEnumerable<DataRow> results
        = from row in myDataSet.Tables["Sent"].AsEnumerable()
          select row;

    // enumerate through results
    foreach (DataRow row in results)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());
    }
```

What can I do to fix this?  Also, if anyone has an easier way to use databases in C#, I am open to your ideas because this has been ridiculous for me (manipulating a database in c#).  Thank you for your help.

**Update 6/29/12:**

The following code works for me:

```
        // get connection strings from app.config
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        // connection object
        SqlCeConnection myConn = new SqlCeConnection(conString);

        // create adapter
        SqlCeDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Sent]", myConn);

        // create command builder
        SqlCeCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(myAdapter);

        // create dataset
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        // fill dataset into named table
        myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sent");

        // create new row
        DataRow newRow = myDataSet.Tables["Sent"].NewRow();

        // set field vals
        newRow["sendTo"] = sendTo;
        newRow["subject"] = subject;
        newRow["message"] = message;

        // add new row to table
        myDataSet.Tables["Sent"].Rows.Add(newRow);

        // update database
        myAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        int updatedRows = myAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "Sent");
        //MessageBox.Show("There were "+updatedRows.ToString()+" updated rows");

        // close connection
        myConn.Close();
```

Comment: The first thing you need to check is whether your connection string is OK and if it points to the right server/database.

Comment: First step: read the message and act on it. Second step: Google the message.

Comment: I concur with @usr.  The error message is very self-explanatory and, even if it isn't for some reason, a few seconds with Google turns up the answer to this really quickly.  The problem is with your connection string or the SQL server itself.  This question doesn't belong here.  It is expected that you do at least some cursory research before asking a question here.

Comment: Is the database server working OK? Can you connect to it in Sql Server Management studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Exception when remotely connection to SQL Server 2005 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800741/c-sharp-exception-when-remotely-connection-to-sql-server-2005-instance)

Comment: Guys, thanks for your responses.  Trust me, I have been googling this stuff like non-stop.  I am not a newbie programmer, I am an expert in PHP.  I am starting to use c# and I am amazed at the difficulty of this simple task.  I have tried numerous ways to connect and manipulate a database, but nothing has been successful.  I am not connecting to a database server, I am just using a local database.  What can I do to make this thing work?

Comment: Can you connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio or any database management tool?

Comment: I don't know how to do that + this is a local database so I'm not sure how that would be possible. I just want to get "a" database working, so even if you can send me a sample file with code that you know works well, that would be good, too.

Comment: I updated the question with the proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using the correct code (it didn't have anything to do with any connection stuff).  This was my first crack at trying to connect to a database in a language other than PHP.  Now, I would probably use LINQ or Lambda expressions than this code.  But here is what I used which worked:

```
    // get connection strings from app.config
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    // connection object
    SqlCeConnection myConn = new SqlCeConnection(conString);

    // create adapter
    SqlCeDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Sent]", myConn);

    // create command builder
    SqlCeCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(myAdapter);

    // create dataset
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    // fill dataset into named table
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sent");

    // create new row
    DataRow newRow = myDataSet.Tables["Sent"].NewRow();

    // set field vals
    newRow["sendTo"] = sendTo;
    newRow["subject"] = subject;
    newRow["message"] = message;

    // add new row to table
    myDataSet.Tables["Sent"].Rows.Add(newRow);

    // update database
    myAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
    int updatedRows = myAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "Sent");
    //MessageBox.Show("There were "+updatedRows.ToString()+" updated rows");

    // close connection
    myConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **check your connection string** error is telling you straight "Hey, I cannot connect to your Database"

Second: `select * from Sent` **(without apostrophes)**

Comment: Has nothing to do with the error message, although you are right with this.

Comment: I am just trying to connect to a local database.  Here is my app.config:
        <add name="TestingApp.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />

I don't know what the correct connection string would be, perhaps you can tell me.  My database is simply located in the same directory as the project at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestingApp\TestingApp\Database1.sdf (also in the \bin folder).

Answer (score 1):

Did you changed the password you use in the machine where the SQL server is installed? I experienced this before, and what I did was to reflect my new password to the SQL Server configuration, then restart the service.

Please also make sure the the TCP/IP setting is enabled in the SQL configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of error will arise when we did not change the tcp/ip setting in sql server configuration manager.So [we need enable the tcp/ip property to resolve this error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ea9f0e79-ef69-4d47-9862-d53a1e460003/)

Answer (score 0):

Might be stating the obvious here but have you checked that the SqlExpress service is running?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650231/1095373

Comment: No, I just needed to fix my code.  I updated it on my answer.